# Turtlebot: arm.launch returns KeyError: ´arm_shoulder_pan_joint´

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm, arbotix

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**Background**: 
Turtlebot: new, arrived with the arm assembled and with all required packages installed from factory. I installed turtlebot_viz for the dashboard as suggested [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/11121/unable-to-launch-turtlebot_dashboard) and updated all ros packages.
[EDIT] The exact same thing happened with a second turtlebot: literally took out of the box and typed: roslaunch turtlebot_arm_bringup arm.launch. Got the exact same error: [Error message](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/Turtlebot2-error%20message%20first%20try%20arm%20launch%20May%2021), [log file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/Turtlebot%202-first%20try%20arm%20launch%20May%2021.log) and [actions log](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/Turtlebot%202-log%20of%20actions.txt)</br/>
Turtlebot laptop: lenovo x130e AMD fusion processors E-450. Ubuntu: 10.04, kernel linux 2.6.32-40-generic. ros: electric
Machine: Intel Core i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz x 4. 32-bit. Ubuntu: 11.10 (upgraded from 11.04). ros: electric

**Problem description**:
Following the [kinect calibration tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_kinect_arm_calibration/Tutorials/CalibratingKinectToTurtleBotArm) part 4, both ssh from the machine specified above, and directly in the turtlebot laptop:
When trying to launch the arm:
*roslaunch turtlebot_arm_bringup arm.launch* 
I am getting:
*KeyError: ´arm_shoulder_pan_joint´*
The full error message is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/error%20message).

The arbotix_python controllerGUI displays and controls the base, but not the joints.
The only related thread I found was [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/12920/turtlebot-electric-service-does-not-start-properly), and my turtlebot already had the fixed file

**Attempts so far**:

1. I tried to trace through the [log
   file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/arbotix-1.txt) but couldn't find a problem. I also tried to debug using pydev (See details below).
2. Both arbotix and the arm packages are updated to newest
   version.
3. Using the arbotix_python terminal
   and command ls: it lists 5 servors
   as required.
4. The [arm.ymal
   file](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/arm.ymal.txt)
   in the turtlebot_arm_bringup package
   contains all 5 joints each with the
   correct id (i.e. shoulder pan id
   1...gripper id 5).

**Debugging details**: 
The call which brings up the error according to the [call stack](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/stack%20call%20edit) indicated in the error message:

```
    try:
        return self.dynamixels[key]
    except:
        return self.hobbyservos[key]
```

has the correct key: arm_shoulder_pan_joint, but both ***dynamixels and hobbyservos are empty***. 
The call stack which tracks why they are empty is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/log%20debugging%20arm%20May%2020). They apparently ***don´t exist in the parameter server***.
The printout of the parameter server from within servos.py is [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/parameters%20in%20parameter%20server).

If anyone has experience or ideas about the source of the problem/solutions, I'll be extremely glad to hear. Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/34081/turtlebot:-arm.launch-returns-keyerror:-%C2%B4arm_shoulder_pan_joint%C2%B4/) by [NTo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2385/nto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-15

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2012-05-19**:
I would expect a more complete error message, with a full traceback, to be printed. Could you post the full error message here?

**Comment by [NTo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2385/nto/) on 2012-05-20**:
Hello fergs, the full error message is here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5858778/error%20message. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is a release issue -- I apparently updated the trunk of turtlebot_arm to be compatible with arbotix 0.7.0 release (Which I haven't got around to actually releasing yet) but then someone tagged a new release without noticing. I'll get a new arbotix release pushed out this weekened to clean this all up.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2012-07-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am able to operate the arm (using *rosrun arbotix_python controllerGUI.py*) by making the following changes. I do not know if I am overriding something else and did not try any of the related demos yet. If anyone recognizes a problem, please let me know. I will also update if there are troubles later on.

1. In file:
   */opt/ros/electric/stacks/turtlebot_arm/turtlebot_arm_bringup/config/arm.yaml*
   Change:

   joints: {

To:

```
dynamixels: {
```

2. In file: */etc/ros/electric/turtlebot.launch*
   Change:

To:

```
<arg name="urdf_file" value="$(find xacro)/xacro.py '$(find turtlebot_arm_description)/urdf/arm.urdf.xacro'" />
```

---

Originally posted by [NTo](https://answers.ros.org/users/2385/nto/) with karma: 51 on 2012-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [learner](https://answers.ros.org/users/4414/learner/) on 2013-04-25**:
This worked for me. thanks :). I have only modified the arm.yaml file.